# How to achieve two multi-step forms, one form on each side using CSS transformation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an object which has one form on one side and another on the other side. On top of that each form has multiple steps.

You can see it in action at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2986690/test/test2.html
I have managed to get CSS transformation right for first form, but in the second form (which triggers when you click "are you a parking seeker?"), when I click "Next" it doesn't move to next step.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all of your scroll functions refer to the "front" class, but the second form uses the "back" class. For example, here's the `scroll_left_4` function:

```
function scroll_left_4(){
    $(".front>div:eq(0)").stop().animate({"margin-left":"-375px"},220);
}
```

You'll either need to create equivalent functions for the second form doing something like this:

```
function scroll_left_4b(){
    $(".back>div:eq(0)").stop().animate({"margin-left":"-375px"},220);
}
```

Or change the code so that is scrolls both front and back at the same time.